# How to open a spec runner in a browser

Tags: code-coverage, karma-jasmine

In [this](https://ariya.io/2013/10/code-coverage-of-jasmine-tests-using-istanbul-and-karma) tutorial it says:

"Opening the spec runner in a web browser will give the expected outcome:"

[image]

But does not mention how to do it. How can I do it?

Example code:

```
var My = {
  sqrt: function(x) {
    if (x < ) throw new Error("sqrt can't work on negative number");
      return Math.exp(Math.log(x)/2);
  }
};
```

Test code:

```
describe("sqrt", function() {
  it("should compute the square root of 4 as 2", function() {
    expect(My.sqrt(4)).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a SpecRunner.html file that references jasmine, your code, and your spec files. Looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.2</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="libs/jasmine-2.0.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/jasmine-2.0.2/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jasmine-2.0.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jasmine-2.0.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jasmine-2.0.2/boot.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```